# Extract coefficients after msmFit

Tags: r, markov-chains, coefficients

I'm trying to extract the parameter estimates (including the matrix of transition probabilities) after running a `msmFit` model. However, I get the following error message:

`summary(msmIre <- msmFit(modIre, 2, sw=rep(TRUE,2)))
coef(msmIre)
Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class`

Any help on this? Moreover, how can I extract the matrix of transition probabilities?

Thank You

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that may be beneficial for future users. 
The way to extract coefficients after msmFit is through the '@':

`msmIre@Coef`